# Error on using pyodbc for connecting to a remote sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using pyodbc for being able to connect from my local machine to a remote server which has installed sql server 2012.
My code looks like:

```
   conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                        'Server=myremoteserver;'
                        'Database=mydb;'
                        'Username=myusername;'
                        'Password=mypass;'
                        )

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable')

for row in cursor: 
    print(row)
```

I got the following error:

***pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.\r\n (10054) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Client unable to establish connection (10054); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')***

I even tried with the port in connection string, both ways, but the same error encountered.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Server=myremoteserver;'
                      'Port=1433;'
                      'Database=mydb;'
                      'Username=myusername;'
                      'Password=mypass;'
                      )

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Server=myremoteserver,1443;'
                      'Database=mydb;'
                      'Username=myusername;'
                      'Password=mypass;'
                      )
```

A connection between the remote server and my local machine could be made within SSMS, and also using the file explorer.
Do you have any suggestion regarding how could be solved?

Comment: [SQL Server Native Client ODBC connections](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver/) use *uid* and *pwd*, not *username* and *password*.

Comment: Add "+" between all the lines when building the connection string.

Comment: @TimMylott, `+` is not necessary in Python if quoted strings are encapsulated in parentheses. See: https://rextester.com/XZG72382.

Comment: @Parfait oh you're right. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Are you sure the port is `1443`? The default port for the default MSSQLSERVER instance is normally `1433`.

Comment: Ah, misspelled when writing the question. yes 1433 I'm using

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15